# Delete blank from column by sql

Tags: mysql

I have data ,some has blank and others not.

Select * from

```
ID, name
1   taro
2   john(there are some blank here)    
3   ken 
4   elle(there are some blank here)
```

I think I could delete blank with php, these code are image.

```
$list = "select * from mytable"

foreach($list as $l){
   $sql = "update mytable('name') value=(trimbyphp($l[name]))"
   $sql->execute()
}
```

However,I would like to delete all blank by sql.

Comment: Does your SQL have a trim() function? Does select trim(name) work? If so, you can do UPDATE table set name=trim(name). Your SQL may have RTRIM and LTRIM, in shich case, you could use RTRIM(LTRIM(name))

Comment: MY one is mysql and `UPDATE CompanyUs set name=trim(name)` works

Comment: At first I think I should loop for each table like php does. however its not necessary, thanks.